# Winmove() not working with citrix app

Tags: vba, excel

I'm back for more help please.
I'm still on the same project as my question a few weeks ago but stuck on another bit.

I have a multiscreen (win 7) set up and am trying to write an application that will start a number of applications and move/resize them in to the correct positions.  I'm doing this as a console app in vb.net.
Following the help I received with my last question I can now start up , move , resize, close all the apps I need bar a couple. 
Unfortunately I need to run two applications through Citrix. 
One is an Excel sheet.
I can find the windows handle for these windows and select them and or close them but MoveWin() or SetWindowPos() doesn't seem to do anything though the title bar of the window I want to move turns blue so I know it is selecting it..
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
A section of the code is pasted below. I'm testing this in excel at the moment and I'll port it across to my console app once working...
Thanks...

```
Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Public Const SWP_FRAMECHANGED = &H20 'Fully redraw the window in its new position.

Sub MoveWin()
    Dim retval As Long
    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim RetWhnd As Long

    hwnd = '123456' 

   retval = SetWindowPos(hwnd, RetWhnd, 0, 0, 600, 400, SWP_FRAMECHANGED) ' Application.hwnd
End Sub
```

Comment: Why am I using excel and vba you may ask ? I've written a handy utility that acts a bit like the spy++ in vs. It lists all the processes and child processes on a sheet that way I can click on a handle then click on close or move etc and test my code out on lot's of different applications without changing the code at all.  This is how I know close move etc works fine for applications running directly in windows but doesn't for one running through citrix. Interesting thing for me is I can move the main citrix window jut not any of the spawned process...

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion about vb.net I've tagged the question  vb.net.  Though my test isn't in vb.net my final solution will be so I'd be glad to receive Vb.net or VB6 advice. How can I add a VB6 flag to my question ? Thanks

Comment: Would anyone have any comments about the following. If I put the move code in to the client app so that as it booted it moved it self to a certain screen position ? Would this work ? How could I send it info to tell it where to go though is it possible to add things to a command line statement ? I have put this question on the Citrix forum but I think I'm the only member on that one , and I haven't been any help to myself ;-)

Comment: And FYI not all windows can be moved by `SetWindowPos()`. I'm not saying this is the case for the Citrix app, but an application can choose to ignore external movement messages.

Comment: The bit about not all windows can be moved by SetWindowPos() is probably what I'm up against. The client is excel so I know excel can be moved and resized when running on the users pc but not when running on the server via Citrix so I'm guessing Citrix filters out the commands.. I have also posted on the Citrix site hoping someone there would be able to give me a definitive yea or nay...

Answer (score 0):

I am not at my home machine, so I cannot confirm this, but I am fairly certain that VB 6 has a tab on the compile dialog (last one perhaps) that has a citrix-related option checkbox.  If it's not there, it might be in the project properties.

Comment: Do you know if this is available in a VBA environment ? I've had a good search about but can't see it at the moment. I guess another question would be , do you know what it does  ? Thanks for the reply....

Comment: In my accounting application, I have one particular user who uses Citrix.  I do not know what it specifically does, but I figured that since I knew of that one client, I'd check the box, since it merely said something to the affect of making the app citrix-compliant.  It did not affect my entire user base so I left it set.  I doubt it's available to VBA, I only saw it specifically in VB 6.0.

Comment: Thanks, Bill, I can't seem to find out much about it but it looks like it maybe a thing to include in the compiled app to make it behave better as a client side app. But I haven't had any problems running other vb.net or VBA stuff client side so not sure what it does. I'll keep looking.

Comment: I've pored through my application just now and in the MSDN help that came with it and I must have mis-remembered the citrix checkbox - it's not where I remember it being, nor can I find it anywhere else.  Sorry, but good luck in your search for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps someone else. I've contacted the Citrix people and they basically don't know the answer. I at least wanted to know if it was possible. Anyway as far as I can ascertain, the move command doesn't seem to be possible across the Citrix divide. The solution I've come up with is to leave the actual move part of the code in the remotely run app. That is build code in to the apps run through Citrix to look at an ini file on the local machine and receive instructions from it. 
This now works great but will only work for apps that either have ability to run a container language or can be wrapped up somehow..